# How to wait for response from NamedPipeServer?

Tags: c#, named-pipes

I have the following client code, that I write stuff to my `Server` pipe, I was able to read it on the `Server` side but before I could reply back, the client would already try to read the still empty pipe. How do you `wait` on the `NamedPipeClientStream`?

```
using (NamedPipeClientStream pipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", pipename, PipeDirection.InOut))
{
    pipe.Connect(5000);
    pipe.ReadMode = PipeTransmissionMode.Byte;

    byte[] ba = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("hello world");
    pipe.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);

    var result = await Task.Run(() => {
        // this would return as soon as Server finished reading
        // but then server hasn't wrote anything back yet
        pipe.WaitForPipeDrain();

        // sample code on how i am planning to read, not tested,
        // since the pipe is still empty at this point
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(pipe))
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            reader.BaseStream.CopyTo(ms);
            return Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

I don't think I should be using `WaitForPipeDrain` but then there are no other options for my to wait, or to know when is ready to read? There are many examples out there, but none of them shows the proper way for the client to wait for a response.

The example shown from Microsoft seems to be using `ReadLine()` and leveraging `EOL` character when you send string data, but I'm dealing with `byte[]` data ("hello world" is just to get some bytes).

Comment: As long as you are writing async code then you might as well await pipe.ReadAsync().  Do beware that you must use a protocol so you can know when all of the bytes in the transmitted byte[] were received.  You almost surely meant to use PipeTransmissionMode.Message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to wait for data. `NamedPipeClientStream` represents a stream of bytes (it derives from `System.IO.Stream`) and if no data is currently available, reading from pipe (or from `StreamReader` that wraps that pipe) will simply block until data arrives.

For transfering textual data, reading with `StreamReader.ReadLine()` and writing with `StreamWriter.WriteLine()` will work fine. To transfer binary data, you can either encode binary data into textual form (for example using base64 encoding) and keep using `StreamReader.ReadLine()` / `StreamWriter.WriteLine()`. Or you can set server and client pipes into [PipeStream.TransmissionMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.pipestream.transmissionmode?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_IO_Pipes_PipeStream_TransmissionMode) to `Message` mode, and transfer each byte array as a single message, as follows (error checks omitted for brevity):

### Client:

```
class Client
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (NamedPipeClientStream pipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "testpipe", PipeDirection.InOut))
        {
            pipe.Connect(5000);
            pipe.ReadMode = PipeTransmissionMode.Message;

            byte[] ba = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("hello world");
            pipe.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);

            var result = await Task.Run(() => {
                return ReadMessage(pipe);
            });

            Console.WriteLine("Response received from server: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    private static byte[] ReadMessage(PipeStream pipe)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            do
            {
                var readBytes = pipe.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
            }
            while (!pipe.IsMessageComplete);

            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

### Server:

```
class Server
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(
            "testpipe",
            PipeDirection.InOut,
            NamedPipeServerStream.MaxAllowedServerInstances,
            PipeTransmissionMode.Message))//Set TransmissionMode to Message
        {
            // Wait for a client to connect
            Console.Write("Waiting for client connection...");
            pipeServer.WaitForConnection();

            Console.WriteLine("Client connected.");

            //receive message from client
            var messageBytes = ReadMessage(pipeServer);
            Console.WriteLine("Message received from client: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(messageBytes));

            //prepare some response
            var response = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hallo from server!");

            //send response to a client
            pipeServer.Write(response, 0, response.Length);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    private static byte[] ReadMessage(PipeStream pipe)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            do
            {
                var readBytes = pipe.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
            }
            while (!pipe.IsMessageComplete);

            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. This should be mark as answered.